# d3.js simple animation - datasets already generated

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I am working on webapp for presenting a wave animation.
The numerical data is generated by another app - the webapp will take the set of arrays (probably json, but it's not so important now) as input. Each array keeps the heights of wave in it's every place, in exact time step.

Summarizing - n arrays, every of them keeps the wave heights, and I need to depict it.

My current idea is to use d3.js to deal with that. So far I created such script:
        var dataset1 = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                        11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

```
    var dataset2 = [ 3, 7, 10, 16, 18, 22, 19, 15, 12, 10,
                    11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
    var datasetTry = [ 3, 7 ];

    var dataset3 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var dataset4 = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    var storage = [ dataset1, dataset2, dataset3, dataset4 ]


    //Width and height
    var w = 1500;
    var h = 400;
    var barPadding = 1;

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    function updateData(dataset) {
        console.log("updateData");
        console.log(dataset);
    svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
              return 4 + i * ((w - 4) / dataset.length);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
                         return h - (d * 4);  //Height minus data value
                     })
          .attr("r", 3);

        d3.selectAll("circle")
          .data([])
          .exit()
          .transition()
          .delay(2500)
          .remove();
    } 

    var i = 0;    

    function myLoop () { 
       setTimeout(function () { 
          updateData(storage[i]);
          i++;                 
          if (i < 5) {        
             console.log("i = " + i);
             myLoop();        
          }                  
       }, 3000)
    }

    myLoop();
```

It works... a little bit. The data is obviously just random numbers, it's not important yet. 
For now the problem in delays - if I set the delays in removing the data and entering new data to the same (or close) value, it does't work - only the first data is depicted.

I also strongly feel that it's far from the way it should be done.

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Just putting things in a closure structure and calls will make your code much more manageable. Here are some links..

I suspect your timing problem might come from using d3.selectAll and svg.selectAll on the same elements.

Read [this by Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), [this recent article](http://ag.svbtle.com/on-d3-components), [this tutorial](http://bocoup.com/weblog/reusability-with-d3/), and [this tutorial](http://pothibo.com/2013/09/d3-js-how-to-handle-dynamic-json-data/).

Look to create a structure more like this:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data, dateFn)

circles.transition()
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(dateFn(d)) })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(amountFn(d)) })

    circles.enter()
     .append("svg:circle")
     .attr("r", 4)
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(dateFn(d)) })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(amountFn(d)) })
     .on("click", function(d) {
        d3.select("#demoAddRandomAndDelete .value").text("Date: " + d.created_at + " amount: " + d.amount)
     })

    circles.exit()
     .remove()
```

Comment: Do you think that it'll also resolve the problem with timing? I'd really like to have it working at all first, then refactoring.

Comment: I don't really understand how I am supposed to make it yours way. Where there is a adding new dataset? Also as far as I am reading here : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions it tells, that I won't be able to add/remove the data in transition.